# Probability of set of coins with different bias

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a set of $n$ biased coins with the same probability $p$.
I throw them at once. The probability to have $k$ successes is the pmf of the binomial distribution

$f(k,n,p)=\binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$

Now suppose that I have a set of $m+n$ coins coins with a DIFFERENT bias:

- $n$ coins have probability $p_{n}$
- $m$ coins have probability $p_{m}$

How can I get the probability of $k$ successes in that case?

I have a very limited knowledge in statistics and I really lack the math to move move from the (for me not so trivial) binomial distribution to this slightly more complex case.

Comment: You need to sum all the ways to get $i$ successes from the $n-$coins and $k-i$ from the $m-$coins.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

$$P(k) = \sum\limits_{n_1 = 0}^n \underbrace{{n \choose n_1} p_1^{n_1} (1-p_1)^{n - n_1}}_{P_1(n_1)} \underbrace{{m \choose k-n_1} p_2^{k-n_1} (1 - p_2)^{m-k+n_1}}_{P_2(k-n_1)}$$

$$= (1-p_1) p_2^k \binom{m}{k} (1-p_2)^{m-k} \,
   _2F_1\left(-k,-n;-k+m+1;\frac{p_1 (p_2-1)}{(p_1-1) p_2}\right)$$

where $F$ is a hypergeometric function.

Comment: maybe a typo $P_1(n_1)={n \choose n_1} p_1^{n_1} (1-p_1)^{n - n_1}$

Comment: @FedericoDestefanis:  Ah yes... thanks... corrected.